# My ChartBean is called to early when I have no connection with database

Tags: jsf

in my xhtml i have as follows:

```
  <p:barChart  id="horizontal"  
               value="#{ChartBean.categoryModel}" 
               legendPosition="ne"  
               breakOnNull="false" 
               barMargin="3" barPadding="3"
               title="Horizontal Bar Chart"  
               orientation="horizontal" min="0" 
               max="#{ChartBean.count}" 
               style="height:#{ChartBean.ssize}" 
    />
```

When I run my web app i get en Exception telling me

"java.lang.Exception: Not connected"

So I understand this class is loaded as application scope but how can I change it to just load when I view it as in session scope.

Well I did try set is as

```
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>ChartBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.xxx.view.ChartBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
```

But is loads immediately anyway?
What am I missing?

Comment: Ok, to clerify a bit more.
I connect to my database in the bean via the pool, but the pool i not up jet an I am not logged in so its not possible to connect.

I want the connection to be done when I view the page, not before.
So, what can I change to do that

Comment: I thougt I had a caching problem or so but it was a rely stupid error, or not an error. My log files were not deleted as they should so the error looked as if it was still there.